# Configuring Spring Integration QueueChannel for RabbitMQ

Tags: jvm, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am currently using spring AMQP API to connect to RabbitMQ. Basically in my consumer code I am reading the messages asynchronously and making a Bulk insert in elastic search. when I do ack = AUTO I get a moderate speed of 400-500 msg/sec (reading from Queue). when I do ack = NONE the increase in reading speed is huge i.e. it goes to 5000-6000 msg/sec.

The configuration is as follows:

- Linux machine with with 32GB RAM
- JVM arguments:

`-server
-Xms1g -Xmx1g -Xss384k PermSize=256m MaxPermSize=256m`

Now the problem is when I am doing ack = NONE though I am getting a good speed the JVM is getting OutOfMemory after some time and I can see lot of GC is happening in this scenario.

I am planning to use the QueueChannel from Spring integration where I can limit the size of the channel as how much messages it can contain.

How can I implement this with RabbitMQ also is there any other way to achieve a good reading speed like 4000-5000 msg/sec without crashing the JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ack=AUTO`, but set the `prefetch` and `txSize` to, say 1000; that way, an ack will only be sent every 1000 messages (you can tune this value as needed).

Using ackmode=NONE causes messages to accumulate in an unbounded blocking queue within the listener container and will only work if the listener can keep up (OOM means yours can't).

We have an [open JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP-322) to resolve this for ack=NONE, but the above technique is usually sufficient.

You can also improve throughput using the container concurrency settings.

Comment: I already have prefetch count as 750, But I am not using txSize :( what effect that will have? Also can I use QueueChannel of Spring Integration with RabbitMQ because it has size limit etc.

Comment: The `txSize` controls how often we send acks. It's not really a good property name - it has nothing to do with transactions. From the reference manual: "When used with acknowledgeMode AUTO, the container will attempt to process up to this number of messages before sending an ack (waiting for each one up to the receive timeout setting). This is also when a transactional channel is committed. If the prefetchCount is less than the txSize, it will be increased to match the txSize.". Using an SI QueueChannel won't help in this scenario - the memory usage is inside the listener container.